# Compass error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint

Tags: drupal-7, guard, compass

For unknown reasons my Drupal Omega 4 subtheme dev environment stopped working all  of a sudden. I have narrowed the problem down to a Compass issue:

```
 % compass watch
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
    error sass/layouts/sidebar/sidebar.layout.scss (Line 3: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /home/<myproject>/public_html/sites/all/themes/<myproject-theme>/sass
  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@omega.<myproject-theme>/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@omega.<myproject-theme>/gems/compass-normalize-1.5/stylesheets
  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@omega.<myproject-theme>/gems/susy-2.2.5/sass)
    error sass/layouts/sidebar/<myproject>-sidebar.layout.scss (Line 4: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
```

Guard is running without errors but is not compiling on scss file changes.

```
% guard start -i
07:25:07 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/<myproject>/public_html/sites/all/themes/<myproject-theme>'
```

I tried emptying the gemset with

`rvm gemset empty`

and reinstalling everything with Bundler

`bundle install`

I have used the instructions here for setting up my environment:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1936970

I have a `.ruby-version` file in my project folder specifying version 2.2.1.

All help very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing `config.rb` file that Compass needs to compile the Sass files.

Now Compass reports ready for action:

```
 % guard start -i

07:27:21 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
07:27:21 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/<myproject>/public_html/sites/all/themes/<myproject-theme>'
```

I must have deleted it by mistake - and since it was included in my .gitignore, I had no way of knowing this.

Lesson learned: do not exclude `config.rb` in `.gitignore`!